# How to make an iOS app start where it left off

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, continue

I'm making an iOS app through `UIStoryboard` mode and I wanted to know if there was a way to add something so when the user leaves the application, it'll continue where the user left off next time he launches the application. 
By the way, I'm making a simple `UIStoryboard` application like I mentioned earlier that only has simple pages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this section in the documentation where Apple briefly touches on this topic.

[Preserving the State of Your App’s User Interface](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW8)

I think this is the general idea of how you would do this, the Three20 framework does this by using URLs, you may attempt to adopt this design as well. This is not to say you should USE Three20 but you can gain some ideas from seeing how they solve this problem.

[Persistence in Three20 Framework](http://three20.info/showcase/persistence)